# Pure css grid problem when changing the chrome screen size to mobile size

Tags: css, css-grid, pure-css

I try to use pure css grid system like explained in the [documentation](https://purecss.io/start/#build-your-pure-starter-kit) but I'm not able to make it work on desktop resolution and mobile like Pixel 2 resolution.

Instead of going on 2 lines like this :

[image]

I got this letter-spacing problem and the div goes on the same line :

[image]

[Like to code example](https://codepen.io/jobou363/pen/dyyRzjW)

```
    <div class="pure-g">
            <div class="pure-u-sm-1-1 pure-u-md-1-1 pure-u-lg-9-24">
                <div class="l-box">
                  <span class="fa-stack">
                    <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-1And5x"></i>
                    <strong class="fa-stack-1x label-white">4</strong>
                  </span>
                    <label>Test:</label>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="pure-u-sm-1-1 pure-u-md-1-1 pure-u-lg-15-24">
                <div class="l-box">
                    <input class="pure-radio" id="montant" name="montant" type="text" value="">

                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem with your grid system and your media queries.

`sm` specifies the behavior only for screen sizes with a width of at least 568px. Below that your problem occurs.

To solve this add the `pure-u-1-1` class respectively - you could say it defines your standard behavior. This alone won't work though because you make use of another stylesheet for *normalizing* your CSS. Put your *normalizing* CSS file in front of the other stylesheet in your code, otherwise it overrides some of your other CSS rules (keyword **cascading** style sheet). Always mention your *normalizing* CSS files first!

Also in this case the `pure-u-md-1-1` class seems obsolete because it does not specify another behavior than `pure-u-sm-1-1`. The latter already defines the same behavior for all screen sizes of at least 568px.